# How to count the number of successive duplicates in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a list, and returns the number of successive duplicate elements in the list.

For example, given `[1;2;3;3;4;4;5]`, the function should return `2`

This is my initial implementation, but unfortunately it always returns `0`. I'm not quite sure where the bug lies.
Any help on how to improve it will be highly appreciated.

```
let rec count_successive_duplicates (lst: int list) (count: int) : (int) =
  match lst with
    | [] | [_]-> 0
    | x :: y :: tl ->
      if x = y then count_successive_duplicates (y::tl) (count + 1) else count_successive_duplicates (y::tl) count
  ;;

let () =
  print_int (count_successive_duplicates [1;2;3;3;4;4;5] 0)
```

Comment: You'll need to get a maximum somewhere. Your count currently does increase sometimes, but a) doesn't reset when a new sequence is encountered b) in the end it always returns `0` anyway

Comment: I see that I'm not using the incremented count when it's available. Thanks for the tip. I've seen the bug now

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you want to do, I thought you wanted to count the *longest* sequence of duplicates. But yeah, it's only a small bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, you'll want to return the accumulator with the count instead of `0` always:

```
let rec count_successive_duplicates (lst: int list) (count: int) : (int) =
  match lst with
    | [] | [_] -> count
(*                ^^^^^ */)
    | x :: y :: tl -> count_successive_duplicates (y::tl) (count + if x = y then 1 else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but as a further suggestion, we can decompose this problem.

Let's get pairs.

```
# let rec pairs = function
    | [] | [_] -> []
    | a::(b::_ as tl) -> (a, b) :: pairs tl;;
val pairs : 'a list -> ('a * 'a) list = <fun>
# pairs [1;2;3;4;5;5;6;7];;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 5); (5, 5); (5, 6); (6, 7)]
```

And now let's define `count` that counts values in a list which return true for a predicate function.

```
# let count f lst =
    List.fold_left 
      (fun i x -> if f x then i + 1 else i) 
      0 lst;;
val count : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> int = <fun>
# pairs [1;2;3;4;5;5;6;7]
  |> count @@ fun (a, b) -> a = b;;
- : int = 1
```

But this isn't very efficient, as we have to generate a whole list of pairs and *then* iterate over it despite the fact that once we're done with a pair we don't really care about it again. Since this question was asked OCaml 4.07+ have the [`Seq` module](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) which will allow us to make this a lazy operation and avoid the need to keep an entire list in memory.

```
# let pairs_seq lst =
    let rec aux lst () =
      match lst with
      | [] | [_] -> Seq.Nil
      | a::(b::_ as tl) -> Seq.Cons ((a, b), fun () -> aux tl ())
    in
    aux lst;;
val pairs_seq : 'a list -> unit -> ('a * 'a) Seq.node = <fun>
# let rec seq_count f s =
    Seq.fold_left (fun i x -> if f x then i+1 else i) 0 s;;
val seq_count : ('a -> bool) -> 'a Seq.t -> int = <fun>
# [1;2;3;4;5;5;6;7] 
  |> pairs_seq 
  |> seq_count @@ fun (a, b) -> a = b;;
- : int = 1
```